# getting local variable value outside in bash script

Tags: bash

I am new to bash script trying to read a file and if the matching string exists, i am putting something in the variable value. i guess it is considering it as a local variable and i am not able to use the value in later part of code. 
How to get this value outside?? Please give me all the possible ways

```
if(...)
then
    ..........
elif (file exists)
then
    cat file | while read line
    do
    if [ "$line" = "something" ]
    then 
        value="correct"
    fi
    done
elif()
.........
fi
echo "value is $value"
```

output:
value is

Answer (score 2):

The `while` loop is being run in a separate process because it's on the right-side of the pipe, so it can't modify its parent environment.  Use redirection instead:

```
 while read line
 do
    # ...
 done < file
```

Comment: oh i understood the reason now. thanks. can you please elaborate how your code works.

Answer (score 1):

Just define `value` earlier in your code, for instance on your first line:

```
value=""
if (file exists)
then
    cat file | while read line
    do
    if [ "$line" = "something" ]
    then 
        value="correct"
    fi
    done
elif()
.........
fi
echo "value is $value"
```

Comment: The parameter `value` being set in the while loop is still a separate parameter from the one you initialize prior to the if statement.